# How to install mpi4py in a separation environment

Tags: python, mpi4py, mpich

I have tried installing mpi4py using `pip install mpi4py`, but it gives me the error:

```
mpi.h no such file or directory
could not build wheel for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

I found that the system does not have `libopenmpi-dev`, but I cannot install it in a separate environment, due to some network error. How can I install mpi4py regardless?

Comment: mpi4py is just a wrapper as far as I know. You need to install mpich2 or openmpi first. This has nothing to do with Python or its enviroment.

Comment: before installing mpi4py, make sure the commands mpirun or mpiexec exist in your system

Comment: What do you mean, "install it in a separate environment"? Did you create one, and if so, how? And then, what kind of network error? Since you managed to install mpi4py, it's not so much downloading the files; it might be that libopenmpi-dev, which appears to be an OS package, not a PyPI package, is hosted on a server with connection problems, but usually, you can redirect to another server.

Comment: I am in a environment which cannot visit web, so can I first download the mpich2 or openmpi and second move it to my own environment and then install it manually? which lib should I download? maybe it needs some others dependencies?